# Using a button to re-start an algorithm

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple math game. Now I've researched all over the internet, and worked on it for hours, but I can't seem to make this simple game to work.

**How the game works:**
The game asks the user a question, the user gives the answer in a entry bar, the user clicks the button, and the user receives another question.

**The problem:**
How can I make it looping, so everytime the user answers a question, the loop / algorithm starts over. So the algorithm can only proceed, when the button is clicked.

**Additional information:**
I am using Tkinter as the GUI. And here is my flowchart:
https://s31.postimg.org/pzs2m43kb/The_Math_Game_algorithm.png

**My problem is in the class GamePage under the while < 10 loop.**

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk as tkk
import random

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")

""" Functions """


""" GUI """
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, GamePage, ValidationPage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="TheMathGame", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        labelStart = tk.Label(self, text="Click start to continue",)
        labelStart.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tkk.Button(self, text="Start", command = lambda: controller.show_frame("GamePage"))
        button1.pack()

class GamePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.count = 0
        self.price = 0

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='Answer the question', font=TITLE_FONT)
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)




        while self.count < 10:
            MathQuestion, MathAnswer = self.mathGenerator()
            self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text=MathQuestion)
            self.label2.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

            userInputField = tk.Entry(self)
            userInputField.pack()


            buttonNext = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=lambda: self.validationManager(MathAnswer, userInputField))
            buttonNext.pack()


    def mathGenerator(self):
        def answerMath(number1, number2, function):
            if function == "+":
                return number1 + number2
            if function == "-":
                return number1 - number2
            if function == "*":
                return number1 * number2
            if function == "/":
                return number1 / number2

        def numberGenerator():
            number1 = random.randint(1, 100)
            number2 = random.randint(1, 100)
            return (number1, number2)

        def subtractFunction(math_function):
            number1, number2 = numberGenerator()

            while number1 < number2:
                number1, number2 = numberGenerator()
            else:
                question = ("%d %s %d" % (number1, math_function, number2))
                answer = answerMath(number1, number2, math_function)
                return (question), (answer)

        def divideFunction(math_function):
            number1, number2 = numberGenerator()

            while number1 % number2 != 0 or number1 < number2:
                number1, number2 = numberGenerator()
            else:
                question = ("%d %s %d" % (number1, math_function, number2))
                answer = answerMath(number1, number2, math_function)
                return (question), (answer)

        math_functions = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
        math_function = (random.choice(math_functions))

        if math_function == '/':
            (question), (answer) = divideFunction(math_function)
        elif math_function == '-':
            (question), (answer) = subtractFunction(math_function)
        else:
            number1, number2 = numberGenerator()
            if math_function == '*':
                math_function_string = 'x'
            else:
                math_function_string = math_function
            question = ("%d %s %d" % (number1, math_function_string, number2))
            answer = answerMath(number1, number2, math_function)
        return question, answer

    def validationManager(self, questionAnswer, userAnswer):
        questionAnswer = questionAnswer
        userAnswerd = userAnswer.get()

        if int(userAnswerd) == questionAnswer:
            return "Correct"
        else:
            return "Wrong"

class ValidationPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.labelText = 'Wrong..'
        self.ValidationLabel = tk.Label(self, text=self.labelText, font=TITLE_FONT)
        self.ValidationLabel.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = App()
    root.iconbitmap('Tesla.ico')
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(350, 250))
    root.title("TheMathGame")

    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="monkey.gif")
    label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
    label.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big problem with tkinter is that while loops that require user interact to exit kills it.

Here are my adjustments.

```
class GamePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.count = 0
        self.price = 0

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='Answer the question', font=TITLE_FONT)
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        self.label2 = tk.Label(self)
        self.label2.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        self.userInputField = tk.Entry(self)
        self.userInputField.pack()

        buttonNext = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.validationManager)
        buttonNext.pack()

        self.askQuestion()

    def askQuestion(self):
        self.userInputField.delete(0, tk.END)
        MathQuestion, self.MathAnswer = self.mathGenerator()
        self.label2.config(text = MathQuestion)

    def validationManager(self):
        if int(self.userInputField.get()) == self.MathAnswer:
            self.price += 1
        self.count += 1

        print(self.count, self.price)

        if self.count == 10:
            print("To the price page")
        else:
            self.askQuestion()
```

You were also trying to return a value from a function called by the button click, this won't really work. It's best to have the function called perform an action instead, meaning do everything that should happen when the button is pressed.

Well what's there is incomplete, you'll need to play with it to display "Correct", "Incorrect" and anything else. But this should shed so light on what was wrong.